# Why the line XXX showing an error saying java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException?

Tags: multidimensional-array, floating-point

//Firstly I need to create a 2-D array of floating points(randomly generated) and store them in a text file no of rows and columns are user input

import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class ClaransS {

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
    // *********************************************************************
    // Variables declaration n-no.of rows k-forget it for now n_o_d-no. of
    // columns
    // *********************************************************************
    int n, k, n_o_d;
    // *********************************************************************
    // Creating the text file to store data
    // *********************************************************************
    File f = new File("C:/x/y/clarans.text");

    try {
        f.createNewFile();
    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    // *********************************************************************
    // Taking user inputs
    // *********************************************************************
    Scanner userInputScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the no. of data you want to cluster");
    n = userInputScanner.nextInt();
    System.out.println(n);

    System.out.println("Enter the no. of clusters you want to form");
    k = userInputScanner.nextInt();
    System.out.println(k);
    System.out
            .println("Enter the no. of dimensions each data will be in a space of");
    n_o_d = userInputScanner.nextInt();
    System.out.println(n_o_d);
    userInputScanner.close();

    // *********************************************************************
    // Storing random data in the data-set
    // *********************************************************************
    double data_set[][] = new double[n][n_o_d];
    int count = 1;
    int i = 0;
    int j = 1;

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        data_set[i][0] = count;
        for (j = 1; j <= n_o_d; j++) {
```

//THIS LINE GIVES ERROR
                data_set[i][j] = (double) Math.random();//YES THIS ONE XXX

```
        }
        count++;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j <= n_o_d; j++) {
            try (PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(
                    new FileWriter(f, true)))) {
                out.print(data_set[i][j] + "\t");
            } catch (IOException e) {
            }
        }
        try (PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(
                new FileWriter(f, true)))) {
            out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

The error is in test condition of for 
(j = 1; j <= n_o_d; j++). 
Test condition will be  j < n_o_d